# How can I restrict the Directions API from returning direction steps that include u-turns?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-api-directions

We use the Directions API from Mapbox and our drivers cannot make u-turns legally because of their vehicle size. Is there a way to restrict the Directions API from returning directions which include u-turns, and instead return alternative routes?